# Laravel Routing URL Parameters with POST Request

Tags: php, laravel, post, routes

If I have a route like the following.

```php
Route::post('/user/{id}', 'UserController@my_function');
```

How do I set up the controller function to be like this so I can use the URL parameter and POST request body data? I'd expect it to be similar to the below code, but is this correct?

```php
public function my_function($id, Request $request){}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way you doing is correct according to the laravel docs.

> If your controller method is also expecting input from a route parameter, list your route arguments after your other dependencies. For example, if your route is defined like so:

```
 Route::put('user/{id}', 'UserController@update');
```

> You may still type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request and access your id parameter by defining your controller method as follows:

Here is a example using the data you send it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Update the given user.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @param  string  $id
     * @return Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
       $request->all() // here you're acessing all the data you send it
       $user = User::find($id) // here you're getting the correspondent user from the id you send it

    }
}
```

For more info: [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers)

Answer (score 1):

When ever you expose your url arguments like that you have to use a get request parameter to pass it through e.g localhost:3000/user/1

`Route::get('/user/{id}', 'UserController@my_function');`

`public function my_function($id){
    //do something 
}`

But if you pass an id under the hold i.e hidden through post.

`Route::post('/user', 'UserController@my_function');`

`public function my_function(Request $request){
    // do something
    $request->id
}`

Maybe this is what you wanted to do

`Route::put('user/{id}', 'UserController@my_function');`

`public function my_function($id){
    //do something 
}`

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your second example is not what I wanted to do but I thank your response

Answer (score 0):

its ok but i love passing the id like this when i am returning a view

```
public function my_function(Request $request){
return view('myfile',['id'=>$id]);
}
```

Comment: That's another way to do it, thank you I may use this method in some occasions